# Excel formula to return position that a number fit in a number grid

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Let's say I have 4 numbers e.g. 4, 10, 15, 20

I need to write a formula that takes a number input and tells me where it fits in the number ranges:

- <= 4
- > 4 and <= 10
- > 10 and <= 15
- > 15 and <= 20
- > 20

So depending on the number input I would need a return value of 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.

I can write a VBA function but thought there might be a convenient function already available....

Comment: The worksheet function `MATCH` can do this.

Comment: Looks like MATCH would work except for the first case (when it's <= 4), which returns #N/A.  I can handle that with an extra IF function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use VLOOKUP to achieve the same thing, as long as you create a 'Lookup' table with the ranges you need like:

[image]

Note the TRUE at the end of the VLOOKUP formula, which returns the last result which is < the lookup value.  Normally, this option is useless - this is one of the few times it is useful.

I prefer this to the VBA method since it is easier to update and accessible to more beginner and intermediate Excel folk too.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your macro

```
my_numb = ActiveCell

Select Case my_numb
Case Is <= 4
  my_val = 1
Case Is <= 10
  my_val = 2
Case Is <= 15
  my_val = 3
Case Is <= 20
  my_val = 4
Case Is > 20
  my_val = 5
Case else
  my_val = "error"
End Select

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = my_val
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to use an if-elseif-end if statement. A Select Case with the two ranges can get rather complcated.

```
x(0) = 4
x(1) = 10
x(2) = 15
x(3) = 20
For k = 0 to 3
    If x(k) <= 4 Then
        y=1
    elseif x(k) > 4 And x(k) <= 10 Then
        y=2
    elseif ...
        ...
    end if
 Next k
```